# Android Emulator unable to connect to Flipper

Tags: android, flipper

I followed the instructions here https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/android-native/#diagnostics. I added the 3 dependencies in `build.gradle`, and added the application class with the same implementation as in the guide, and linked to it in manifest.
However flipper still says "No device found":

[image]

I ran the diagnostics command  `adb shell am start -n <package_name>/com.facebook.flipper.android.diagnostics.FlipperDiagnosticActivity` and saw that "establish pre-setup connection" and "connect insecurely" failed:

[image]

I'm not sure what these errors mean and how to fix them. Would appreciate help!

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. If you find a way to resolve it please share it with me.

Answer (score 35):

I had the same issue and this worked on my side:

In the flipper application:

- Open the Settings from the bottom left gear wheel, then "Settings"
- Change the "Android SDK location" value to the path to the platform tools, something like this: `/Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

[image: Flipper configuration]

- Click on "Apply and restart".

Answer (score 0):

try running :

```
adb shell am start -n <YOUR_APPLICATION_ID>/com.facebook.flipper.android.diagnostics.FlipperDiagnosticActivity
```

**Ref:**
Follow the steps at: https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/troubleshooting/android/#in-app-diagnostics.

Need to add `FlipperDiagnosticActivity` to `AndroidManifest.xml` & `ReactNativeFlipper.java` are matching.
This resolved my issue after making sure app ids of the above are matching.